# Establishing connection to couchbase from microservices deployed in PCF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, cloud-foundry

I have read that when building microservices below must be taken into account -

1. Split microservices based on business domain rather than technology layer such as DAO
2. All services must be self-contained - which I assume is that it shouldn't have many external dependencies. For instance if the service needs to interact with an external DB and uses 10 queries , all this should be within DAO layer of the app and this shouldn't be an external library which is shared by multiple microservices.

I have an existing legacy app which I am planning to convert into a microservice. The legacy app interacts with Couchbase DB. We have library project which connects to couchbase db included within the existing legacy app. In the current setup , we are using weblogic and the app is deployed in about 16 weblogic farms. Each app creates its own connection to the DB and this is resulting in number of connections being opened to the CB server.

The app is small enough & comprises of only one business domain. So I am planning to convert the whole app into a microservice. I will be  deploying this into pivotal cloud foundry platform. When deploying the app into PCF , I will be creating multiple instances of the app and I guess I will run into the same issue that I am facing with the legacy app. As part of the design , one the options that I was evaluating is to expose the DAO layer as another microservice so that I can throttle the number of connections to couchbase DB. However based on the points that I had listed above , I assume it is not a good practice. Please let me if my understanding is incorrect.

Another option that I am evaluating is to use a user provided service in PCF to establish a connection to couchbase server. However I am not sure if this create a connection pool which can be used by all deployed apps.

Please let me know your views on the approaches listed above and also if there is any other recommended approach. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The plan you desribed would convert the one legacy application into one 'micro service' which will be run with many instances (at the end 16 again). As you said, this leaves you with the same problems as before.

The main problem seems to be the database. You have only one database for all instances and that is the bottleneck. However you have couchbase, so you could use a cluster and gain scalability.

If you really want to use **micro** services, you need to split up the legacy application into smaller parts, each dealing only with a part of the business domain.

Sharing one database among many micro services is a known anti pattern, as you see in your case.

With every micro service responsible for only a part of the domain, each one only needs access to a subset of the database. Ideally each micro service will have its own database allowing to freely choose the persistence technology, caching and other optimizations.

That is the benefit you can get from micro services. This does not come for free, it needs some effort to get it right.

**Regarding sharing external libraries**
I would not consider sharing technical libraries a problem. You do that anyway for example spring boot.

It indeed gets problematic if you share libraries that are business domain related. This means, that many micro services are concerned with the same thing. And this is the opposite of 'separation of concerns', one of the main goals of micro services.services.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for the detailed answer. This is helpful. I have couple additional questions. The legacy app that I am trying to convert deals with only one domain and it is a pretty small service. When we were deploying this instance into multiple servers it was creating multiple threads and couchbase team mentioned we need to limit the number of threads we are opening. We are planning to increase the number of nodes however , we also want a mechanism to throttle the number of connections we are creating.

Comment: We are using pivotal cloud foundry. It provides service broker abstraction , so wanted to see if it does let creating connections that can be shared by deployed Apps